# Is there any way to make a unit, with a multiple turn move queued, move immediately?

Tags: civilization-5

Is there any way to get a unit to move *now*, that has been given a multiple-turn move command (i.e. move way over to there)?  (... as opposed to during the end-of-turn processing)

In More Detail:  Sometimes I have a unit that is on some particular hex right now, and will move off it at the end of the turn because it has been instructed to go somewhere, that takes multiple turns... and I want to move *another* unit onto *that* tile *now*.

I do not want to re-issue the move instruction, (a) because that is annoying, and (b) because it is sometimes not apparent where this particular unit is supposed to be going.

Comment: A difficult concept to explain but I know exactly what you mean - hopefully someone knows a solution for this.  It happens with build orders too, for example on roads when building a route.

Answer (score 2):

### No, there isn't a way.

A unit moves during end-of-turn processing in order to allow the player to (if he needs be) change the unit's action mid-way through the turn.

**Think of this:**
If your unit moves, into a region that has an enemy, being aware they're there... Your unit will become fodder as it can't escape/attack, as its turn's move have already been used on the queued actions.